# gl_PointSize OpenGLES clarification

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader, pixel-shading

What does setting `gl_PointSize = 1.0` in vertex shader means or achieve? Does that mean the vertex itself is a pixel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does setting gl_PointSize = 1.0 in vertex shader means or achieve? Does that mean the vertex itself is a pixel?

Yes, it does.

See [`gl_PointSize`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/gl_PointSize.xhtml):

> The variable `gl_PointSize` is intended for a vertex shader to write the size of the point to be rasterized. **It is measured in pixels.**

See [OpenGL ES Specification - Khronos OpenGL ES Registry, 3.3 Points, page 51](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf):

> Point size is taken from the shader builtin `gl_PointSize` and clamped to the
>   implementation-dependent point size range. If the value written to `gl_PointSize` is less than or equal to zero, results are undefined. The range is determined by the ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE and may be queried as described in chapter 6.
>   The maximum point size supported must be at least one. 
>   **Point rasterization produces a fragment for each framebuffer pixel whose center lies inside a square centered at the point’s (*xw*, *yw* ), with side length equal to the point size.**

This means, if you define `gl_PointSize = 1.0`, then this specifies a square with a side lenght of 1 fragment. The fragment whos center point is in this square is affected.

In compare to "desktop" OpenGL, in program point size has not to be enabled. (In desktop OpenGL `gl_PointSize` only has a meaning, if **`GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE`** is enabled).

Comment: Under Android there is no such constant named GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE. But gl_PointSize can still be set in vertex shader and it works.

Comment: @neoexpert Yes, you are right. That's a difference between OpenGL ES and "desktop" OpenGL

Answer (score 3):

gl_PointSize determines the size of a point.

You can draw in triangles, lines and points. If you'll draw for example a triangle  in points, then 3 points will appear on the screen. There size can be changed with gl_PointSize parameter. If you set for example gl_PointSize = 10.0; , then points on screen will be quite big.

What is this for? Gives more possibilities. Also a texture can be bound to a point - wherever you draw a point there'll be a texture. Cool, hah? And the size of this texture in this case is determined by gl_PointSize;

Not much sure in what range it can be changed. I guess it depends a bit. Just try (1.0, 4.0, 10.0 for example) and you'll quickly see the difference.